# Calculating the required capacity for a straming server

Tags: audio, video-streaming, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

How can I / Whats the correct method to calculate the required server capacity for a steaming server if I estimate 62,500 users / hour for 5 hours.

Comment: At what bit rate? Is it adaptive streaming? Are you using a CDN?

Comment: It is impossible to tell you anything useful.  You haven't told us what you're streaming, and at what bitrates.  All I can tell you is that you're going to need a lot of servers and a ton of bandwidth.  It's definitely best to use an existing CDN rather than build your own, in this case.